# Word Boundary match float followed by optional space

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary

I am trying to match a float followed by an optional space followed by a list of symbols which can be represented as follows

```
price of rldtoken
420 rld.token 0.28 btc
42.37 rldtoken to xrp
42.37rldtoken to xmr
cost of rldtoken
10 btc 12.47 rldtoken to xmr
whatisrldtoken
btcc price
btc cost
0.2btc
```

I am currently using this regex

```
((?:0|[1-9]\d*)?(?:\.\d+)?)\s*\b(rld[\W_]*token|btcc|btc|ark|xmr|xrp)\b
```

broken down as

```
((?:0|[1-9]\d*)?(?:\.\d+)?) Match float
\s* Match 0 or more spaces
\b(rld[\W_]*token|btcc|btc|ark|xmr|xrp)\b Match words
```

which matches all but 42.37rldtoken to xrp and 0.2btc, I am assuming this has to do something with space and word boundaries

If I remove the word boundary, it matches whatisrldtoken which I dont want to match.

Some directions on how to proceed would be super appreciated

EDIT
Everything in action [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/qBRwPp/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use tis regex:

```
(?:(\.\d+|\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*|\b)(rld[\W_]*token|btcc|btc|ark|xmr|xrp)\b
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qBRwPp/4)

To match floating point number it is more accurate to match number starting with dot separately in alternation rather than keeping both parts optional which will result in matching an empty string.

Comment: thank you for attempting but the first one is not being matched "price of rldtoken" the thing is if there is not floating point number, the match still needs to happen in order to take the quantity as 1

Comment: So you want to match an empty string as floating number?

Comment: yup so that I can extract the quantity from it which ll return empty or undefined which i can turn to 1, guess we can do an or here like number with optional space followed by word boundary or just word boundary

Comment: lovely! that seems to work perfectly! thank you very much